# Traversing directories using shell script

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I am trying to traverse all directories under the current directory using a shell script. In each of those sub directories, there is a makefile and I want to execute it. Any idea how to do ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with [find](http://linuxmanpages.com/man1/find.1.php) :

```
find -iname makefile -execdir make -f {} \;
```

That will find every file named `makefile` (or Makefile, or whatever different case for word makefile, thanks to thiton) (recursively) and then launch make against it.

Comment: Slight improvement: "Makefile" is often used as well, so -iname might be more appropriate.

Comment: Well I tried the above method and it didn't work. Perhaps I should have mentioned that the targets of the makefiles are in the subdirectories themselves. Hence I guess we need to manually traverse the subdirectories one by one to get it write (?) .

Comment: @Warangalite : try with `-execdir` instead of `-exec`, it will change directory before executing the command.